# is this temporal phrase with and/or ambiguous

Tags: and-or

> If checked, box 1 does not include loan origination fees and/or
>   capitalized interest *for loans made before September 1, 2004*.

Does the phrase "for loans made before September 1, 2004" modify **capitalized interest** only, or does it also modify **loan origination fees**?

Is the statement equivalent to

**If checked, box 1 includes neither capitalized interest for loans made before September 1, 2004 nor loan origination fees (for loans made at any time).**

Comment: Do you mean it includes one or the other but not both? And what does the time-constraint apply to?

Comment: What about the time phrase?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is ambiguous, but I lean heavily toward interpreting clauses connected by "and/or" to group together all subsequent modifiers, whenever that interpretation makes sense.  So I unpack this as:

> If checked, box 1 does not include (loan origination fees and capitalized interest) for loans made before September 1, 2004.

or

> If checked, box 1 does not include loan origination fees for loans made before September 1, 2004.

or

> If checked, box 1 does not include capitalized interest for loans made before September 1, 2004.

This, by the way, is exactly why "and/or" clauses are considered poor form in many legal and contractual contexts. For instance, it's difficult to get a technical patent through the review process with an or clause in the claims, unless there is significant verbiage to isolate the clause.

Comment: I hate and/or with a passion.

Comment: I agree with your unpacking, BTW, but unless the missing check in the box is an oversight, the bank does not.  :)